# Custom date data type in C

Tags: c, datetime, formatting

I've created a very basic date data type in C simply to practice writing my own data type. Please critique.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
enum DATE_FORMAT{DASHES,SLASHES};
typedef enum DATE_FORMAT DFORMAT;
typedef struct {
    unsigned char day;
    unsigned char month;
    unsigned short year;
} DATE;

/* Allocates new DATE with specified values and returns a ptr to it. User must NULL-check */
DATE *create_date(unsigned char month, unsigned char day, unsigned short year)
{
    if((month > 12) || (month < 1))
        return NULL;
    if((day > 31) || (day < 1))
        return NULL;
    if((year > 9999) || (year < 0))
        return NULL;
    DATE *the_date = malloc(sizeof(DATE));
    if(the_date == NULL)
        return NULL;
    the_date->day = day;
    the_date->month = month;
    the_date->year = year;
    return the_date;
}
void printf_date(DATE *input, DFORMAT format)
{
    if(input == NULL)
        printf("Invalid DATE.\n");
    if(format == DASHES)
        printf("%hhu-%hhu-%hu\n",input->month,input->day,input->year);
    if(format == SLASHES)
        printf("%hhu/%hhu/%hu\n",input->month,input->day,input->year);
    return;
}
void free_date(DATE *dtf)
{
    if(dtf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Date free failed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        free(dtf);
        printf("Date freed successfully\n");
    }
    return;
}


int main()
{
    DATE *my_date = create_date(3,17,2017);
    if(my_date == NULL)
    {
        printf("Please provide a valid date next time... exiting.\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf_date(my_date, SLASHES);
    printf_date(my_date, DASHES);
    free_date(my_date);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> DATE *create_date(unsigned char month, unsigned char day, unsigned short year)
> ```

What if I want to create a `DATE` on the stack?

---

> ```
>     if((month > 12) || (month < 1))
>         return NULL;
>     if((day > 31) || (day < 1))
>         return NULL;
>     if((year > 9999) || (year < 0))
>         return NULL;
> ```

There are many date libraries out there, and they're not consistent on their offsets for months. I would consider creating an enum for the months.

Also, either don't validate the values at all or validate them fully. If I can't create `2017-13-01` then why can I create `2017-02-31`? If I can't create a date in 753 BC then why can I create a date in year 0 (whatever that means – 1 BC?)?

Obviously that comes with some caveats, particularly with respect to the transition from the Julian to the Gregorian calendar; the documentation should make it clear what the transition date is and what days don't exist in consequence.

---

> ```
> void printf_date(DATE *input, DFORMAT format)
> ```

Wouldn't `sprintf_date` be more useful? You can print to stdout given `sprintf`, but you can't print to anything other than stdout given only `printf`.

> ```
>         printf("%hhu-%hhu-%hu\n",input->month,input->day,input->year);
> ```

> ```
>         printf("%hhu/%hhu/%hu\n",input->month,input->day,input->year);
> ```

No. Just no. ISO 8601 is the only date format that should be used unless a locale parameter is supported.

Comment: Strongly agree with "either don't validate the values at all or validate them fully"

Comment: "Wouldn't sprintf_date be more useful?" Good idea.  Then this code set should also provide a macro like `SPRINTF_DATE_N` that would be the size needed to accommodate all possible `sprintf_date()` cases.

Answer (score 2):

It's a nice piece of work. Short, understandable, to the point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

After the includes, there should be an empty line. It's like having a paragraph in a long prose text, to help the reader.

```
enum DATE_FORMAT{DASHES,SLASHES};
typedef enum DATE_FORMAT DFORMAT;
```

Since you don't use the name `DATE_FORMAT`, you can also write it in a single line: `typedef enum { DASHES, SLASHES } DFORMAT`.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char day;
    unsigned char month;
    unsigned short year;
} DATE;
```

Technically speaking, you are right. The date components fit in an `unsigned char` or an `unsigned short`. Nevertheless I would choose `unsigned int` for all of the fields, simply because I want to express that the date components are *integers*. I would only use the smaller types when it comes to hardware-related things.

```
/* Allocates new DATE with specified values and returns a ptr to it. User must NULL-check */
DATE *create_date(unsigned char month, unsigned char day, unsigned short year)
{
    if((month > 12) || (month < 1))
        return NULL;
    if((day > 31) || (day < 1))
        return NULL;
    if((year > 9999) || (year < 0))
        return NULL;
    DATE *the_date = malloc(sizeof(DATE));
    if(the_date == NULL)
        return NULL;
    the_date->day = day;
    the_date->month = month;
    the_date->year = year;
    return the_date;
}
```

Great code. Well, except for the order of parameters. Almost all other people who designed a similar function used the order `year, month, day`. It's simple to remember: from large to small. The American order `month, day, year` is confusing to the rest of the world.

```
void printf_date(DATE *input, DFORMAT format)
{
    if(input == NULL)
        printf("Invalid DATE.\n");
    if(format == DASHES)
        printf("%hhu-%hhu-%hu\n",input->month,input->day,input->year);
    if(format == SLASHES)
        printf("%hhu/%hhu/%hu\n",input->month,input->day,input->year);
    return;
}
```

The `return` at the end is redundant. Just remove it.

If you had chosen `unsigned int` for the date components, the printf specifiers would be the natural `%u` here instead of the distracting `%hhu` and `%hu`, which is much more common and therefore easier to read.

Since you include the `\n` at the end of the output, your function should better be called `println_date`. The standard `printf` function doesn't append a newline, so neither should your function.

```
void free_date(DATE *dtf)
{
    if(dtf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Date free failed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        free(dtf);
        printf("Date freed successfully\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

The `return` is redundant.

As soon as your program works, the `printf` calls must go away.

You can omit the `if` clause, since the `free` function can handle a `NULL` argument. It does nothing in that case.

The parameter name looks weird. Does it mean `date_to_free`? Don't use abbreviations. The name should simply be `date`.

So the code should look like:

```
void free_date(DATE *date) {
    free(date);
}
```

Continuing with your code:

```
int main()
```

Just empty parentheses mean *unspecified number of arguments* for historic reasons. You should write `int main(void)` instead.

```
{
    DATE *my_date = create_date(3,17,2017);
    if(my_date == NULL)
    {
        printf("Please provide a valid date next time... exiting.\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Error messages don't belong on `stdout`. They should be written to `stderr`, like this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Please provide ...");
```

Continuing with your code:

```
    printf_date(my_date, SLASHES);
    printf_date(my_date, DASHES);
    free_date(my_date);
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Very nice. But since `return` is not a function, it shouldn't look like it. Instead, write `return EXIT_FAILURE` without the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a structure such as `DATE`, which may have a very large number of instances, using types narrower than `int/unsigned` makes sense for space economy.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char day;
    unsigned char month;
    unsigned short year;
} DATE;
```

All uppercase tokens like `DATE`, from a style point-of-view, are typically reserved for macro constants.  Still this is valid code.  I would recommend something `date_ymd` instead.

---

The `create_date()` signature unnecessarily conforms to the details of `DATE`.  Why does code use parameter type `unsigned char` for `month`? Looks like an implementation detail.  By using `int/unsigned` parameters, the function is open to wider use.  Else this `DATE` code obliges the calling code to check for type narrowing issues.

The parameter order may be consistent with a certain locale, yet `year, month, day` matches the spirit of [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

The following alternative breaks out aspects of calendar functions that will likely prove useful in other `DATE` functions.

Make public the range of allowable years by adding those limits to `date_ymd.h`

```
// date_ymd.h
#define DATE_YMD_YEAR_MIN 1
#define DATE_YMD_YEAR_MAX 9999
date_ymd *create_date(int year, int month, int day);

// date_ymd.c
static int eom(int year, int month) {
  assert(month >= JAN && month <= DEC);
  static const char month_since_January_length[MONTH_PER_YEAR] = {
    31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
  if (month == FEB && isleapyear(year)) {
    return month_since_January_length[FEB-JAN] + 1;
  }
  return month_since_January_length[month-JAN];
}

static bool valid_date(int year, int month, int day) {
  if(year < DATE_YMD_YEAR_MIN || year > DATE_YMD_YEAR_MAX) {
    return false;
  }
  return month >= JAN && month <= DEC && day >= 1 && day <= eom(year, month);
}

date_ymd *create_date(int year, int month, int day) {
  if (!valid_date(year, month, day)) {
    return NULL;
  } 
  ...
```

---

Rather than allocate to the size of the *type*, allocate to the size of the *referenced variable*.  Easy to code, review and maintain.

```
 // DATE *the_date = malloc(sizeof(DATE));
 DATE *the_date = malloc(sizeof *the_date);
```

---

As `printf_date()` does not alter the pointer data, best to use `const` for wider applicability and better emitted code.

IMO, the name `printf_date()` should reflect the structure's name closer and lead with that.

Let the calling code print a `'\n'` if it needs to.

Some option should match ISO 8601 with its y-m-d order and minimum 4 digit year and 2 digit month/day - zero filled

A `switch` statement is appropriate here.

I'd expect a print function to handle or return the return value from `printf()`, not simply `void` it.

The `"h"` and `"hh"` are OK , but not needed here.

```
int DATE_printf(const DATE *input, DFORMAT format) {
  switch (format) {
    case MDY_DASHES: 
      return printf("%u-%u-%u", input->month, input->day, input->year);
    case ISO_8601:
      return printf("%04u-%02u-%02u", input->year, input->month, input->day);
    ...
```

---

`free()` allows `free(NULL)`, so recommend to follow that idiom with `free_date()`.  No need to print anything.

```
void free_date(DATE *dtf) {
    free(dtf);
}
```